# Repeat rows in SQL with one changing attribute value

Tags: mysql

I have a table looks like table A and I want to force all tags to have records for all shipment years and keep the same shipment value like table B in SQL. I tried to use For() loop in SQL but didn't figured out how, any help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TQqB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT tag,year FROM TABLE A) CROSS JOIN (SELECT shipment from TABLE A)) T
```